How to Efficiently Process 6000 Requests in Python with Limited Time Constraints?
I have a Python script that sends requests to an API to generate responses based on input prompts. Each request typically takes around 10 seconds to process. I have a CSV file containing 6000 rows, and I want to send the values from the 'text' column as input prompts to the API. Additionally, I aim to append the generated responses to a new column in the same CSV file.
Given the large number of requests and the time it takes for each request to complete, I'm concerned about the overall processing time. Is there a way to optimize this process to avoid spending 6000*10 seconds sequentially?
Here's the base code snippet:
import pandas as pd
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
import time

# Define your existing function for sending a request
def send_request(session, input_prompt):
    url = 'https://ai-chat-test.***.workers.dev/'
    consolidated_request = f"""From the input "{input_prompt}", extract key descriptions, deduplicate them, and use these to create a compelling, concise description of the fashion item."""
    return session.post(url, json={"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": consolidated_request}]}, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

# Function to apply send_request concurrently and save intermittently
def apply_concurrent_requests(df, function):
    session = FuturesSession(max_workers=5)
    futures = {function(session, text): index for index, text in enumerate(df['text'])}
    results = [None] * len(df)
    batch_counter = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    for future in as_completed(futures):
        index = futures[future]
        try:
            response = future.result()
            if response.status_code == 200:
                data = response.json()
                for message in data:
                    if message['role'] == 'assistant':
                        results[index] = message['content']
                        break
                else:
                    results[index] = "No assistant message found."
            else:
                results[index] = f"Failed to get a response, status code: {response.status_code}"
        except Exception as e:
            results[index] = f"Exception occurred: {e}"

        # Save after processing each batch of 100 or the last response
        batch_counter += 1
        if batch_counter % 100 == 0 or index + 1 == len(df):
            # Save the responses so far to the DataFrame
            for j, res in enumerate(results[:index+1]):
                df.at[j, 'response'] = res

            # Save to CSV
            df.to_csv('intermediate_metadata.csv', index=False)
            print(f"Processed {index+1} requests in {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds and saved to CSV.")
            start_time = time.time()  # Reset the timer for the next batch

    return df

df = pd.read_csv('metadata.csv')
updated_df = apply_concurrent_requests(df, send_request)
updated_df.to_csv('updated_metadata.csv', index=False)


How can I optimize this process to send multiple requests at once or utilize parallel processing to reduce the overall processing time?

Does this answer your question? Most efficient way to update Dataframe with JSON array from WebService

I gave a generic answer there on how to easily offload your requests to a list comprehension using async requests with requests-futures. There are other async methods that have come around since but I have found them to be very marginally faster, if at all, compared to requests-futures and none win on usability

@roganjosh Thanks, as I read in the code,  session = FuturesSession(max_workers = 10), so basically it will send 10 requests at one go? can we not send all 6000 requests at once?

No, because the server will just outright block you and/or die. You can set your number of workers as you want, but no server is considering 6000 simultaneous requests from a single user, nor is it likely to have the processing power to answer those requests any faster than at least somewhat sequentially

It doesn't just send requests in batches of 10. It sends 10 initial requests simultaneously and then recycles a worker as soon as it becomes re-available, asynchronously. So you're still sending requests pretty much at the limit of what the server can respond to. I absolutely hammer a C++ server on my localhost with this and 10 workers can still overwhelm it at times, but shifts about 500 req/sec

@roganjosh nice understood, but as I find it a little complicated still, could you also help me with the code-based answer I an accept it, would be helpful for others as well. Thanks

The example is already there in the dupe

@roganjosh, I wrote it myself but IMO the speed is slower than from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
therefore I am not sure if my code is correct  and requesting your help :)

@roganjosh I have updated my code,  hopefully you can see and guide me if it is fine :)

response = future.result() is blocking, so it's still going to run synchronously. It would be tough for me to answer this without something to test against

@roganjosh It's basically one LLM that takes the input and returns the enhanced prompt.

I can guess what it is. That doesn't mean I can test against it when there is no API for me to work with. Please look again at the example I linked to right at the start. You should generate the list of requests first before processing them; this will give you a list of Futures that you can then process. Instead, you're firing a request and then processing it immediately once it returns. You can attach a callback to the request, but the way you're doing it will be sequential here

@roganjosh , I have updated the ocde again in the question - do you think this time it's better as I am using 'as_completed'?
